# How to trigger events in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, events, select, handler

I have this Select-field which is generated by a JS-Class:

```
  new select({
                label : "mylabel",                    
                name  : "vermiet",
                values: {
                    "0": "nein",
                    "1"  : "1ver",
                    "2"  : "2ver",
                    "3"  : "3ver"                       
                },
                value: '0',
                events  : {
                    change: {
                        0 : {
                            hide: ['OB1','OB2','OB3'],
                            custom: function () {
                                jQuery('#OB1, #OB2, #OB3).val('');
                            }
                        },
                        1 : {
                            hide: ['OB2','OB3'],
                            show: ['OB1'],
                            custom: function () {
                                jQuery('#OB2, #OB3).val('');
                            }
                        },
                        2 : {
                            hide: ['OB3'],
                            show: ['OB1','OB2'],
                            custom: function () {
                                jQuery('#OB3).val('');
                            }
                        },
                        3 : {                               
                            show: ['OB1','OB2','OB3'],
                            custom: function () {

                            }
                        }  

                    }
                }
            }),
            new input({
                label   : "WE 1",
                name    : "OB1",
            }),
            new input({
                label   : "WE 2",
                name    : "OB2",
            }),
            new input({
                label   : "WE 3",
                name    : "OB3",
            })
```

When this select is changed, it shows/hides the OB1-OB3

Now I want to trigger this change Event from a other Element on my site. I have build a better looking select-field with HTML-Divs & JS, so I set `display:none;` to the original select. When I now change the new HTML-Div-Select, I just can't get the change-event from the original-Select running.

Changing the value of the original-select is no problem, but whatever I try, the original change-event won't run.

I already tried `trigger()` and `triggerHandler()` :/

Can someone tell me what else I could try?

Comment: When you trigger change the original select, I assume you're doing something like this -> $('OriginalAndHiddenSelectSelector').val(valueSelectedOnHtmlDivSelect).trigger("change"), isnt it?

Comment: @Nineoclick .. Yes, I already tried that, but nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

Trigger **must** work. Probably you missed up something. Here's a simple fiddle. Hope this helps. -> https://jsfiddle.net/vxcogk9k/

PS: did you attach events to $(document) ? If not and something comes after document ready, probably it wouldnt never fire.

Regards.

CODE

**HTML**

```
<select id="originalHiddenSelect" style="display:none;">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
</select>

<ul id="fakeVisibleSelect">
<li data-value="1">ONE</li>
<li data-value="2">TWO</li>
<li data-value="3">THREE</li>
</ul>
<div id="selectionResult"><p>YOUR SELECTION RESULT: <strong><span>NONE</span></strong></p></div>
```

**JS**

```
obj = {
    init: function()
  {
    // behaviour on hidden select
    $(document).on('change.originalHiddenSelect', '#originalHiddenSelect', function(e){
        $('#selectionResult').find('span').text($(this).val());
      return;
    });

    // behaviour on "fake select"
    $(document).on('click.fakeVisibleSelect','#fakeVisibleSelect li', function(e){
        var valueToSelectOnHiddenSelect = $(this).attr("data-value");
      $('#originalHiddenSelect').val(valueToSelectOnHiddenSelect).trigger("change.originalHiddenSelect");
      return;
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    obj.init();
})
```

**NOTE** Remember to sign the answer as accepted if it solves your problem. Thankyou.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer... when I reporoduce it in a clean document, it works.. but in my main-project (which is a ES6-framework) it won't work :/